# Add a subview to background / back of stack?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I've created a blur background view which I would like to apply to a particular UIview which contains a number of elements - I would like the new view to be placed behind all other elements.

This is my current code -

```
 [_feedUIView addSubview:blurView ];
```

All works fine - but it places the new view in front - how can I place it at the back?

Comment: did you try sendSubviewToBack api?

Comment: [_feedUIView   insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0  ];  seems to work - is that the best method?

Comment: it works too..!! But its a wrong way to add View at index. If anything change in the future uyour code may breaks..!!

Comment: @Paul yes, `[_feedUIView insertSubview:blurView atIndex:0]` is the way to go if you want to add it directly to the bottom of the view stack.

Answer (score 8):

Just use this after adding it:

```
[_feedUIView sendSubviewToBack:blurView]
```

Answer (score 6):

Do something like this.

```
[_feedUIView  addSubview:blurView];
[_feedUIView sendSubviewToBack:blurView];
```

Comment: That is exactly what I said